# Check if Vector's Lengths are Equal

Tags: idris

Given the following from [Type-Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris):

```
import Data.Vect

data EqNat : (num1 : Nat) -> (num2 : Nat) -> Type where
  Same : (num : Nat) -> EqNat num num                               

sameS : (eq : EqNat k j) -> EqNat (S k) (S j)
sameS (Same n) = Same (S n)

checkEqNat : (num1 : Nat) -> (num2 : Nat) -> Maybe (EqNat num1 num2)
checkEqNat Z     Z     = Just $ Same Z
checkEqNat Z     (S k) = Nothing
checkEqNat (S k) Z     = Nothing
checkEqNat (S k) (S j) = case checkEqNat k j of
                           Just eq => Just $ sameS eq
                           Nothing => Nothing

exactLength : (len : Nat) -> (input : Vect m a) -> Maybe (Vect len a)
exactLength {m} len input = case (checkEqNat m len) of 
                              Just (Same m) => Just input
                              Nothing       => Nothing
```

If I replace the last function's `Just (Same m)` with `Just eq`, the compiler complains:

```
*Lecture> :r
Type checking ./Lecture.idr
Lecture.idr:19:75:
When checking right hand side of Main.case block in exactLength at Lecture.idr:18:34 with expected type
        Maybe (Vect len a)

When checking argument x to constructor Prelude.Maybe.Just:
        Type mismatch between
                Vect m a (Type of input)
        and
                Vect len a (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        m
                and
                        len
Holes: Main.exactLength
```

How does `Just (Same m)`, i.e. the working code, provide "evidence" that `exactLength`'s `len` and `m` are equal?

Answer (score 2):

What I find useful when working with Idris is adding holes when you're not sure about something rather than solving them. Like adding a hole into `Just ...` branch to see what's going on there:

```
exactLength : (len : Nat) -> (input : Vect m a) -> Maybe (Vect len a)
exactLength {m} len input = case (checkEqNat m len) of
                        Just (Same m) => ?hole
                        Nothing => Nothing
```

and then change `(Same m)` to `eq` and back while looking at the results of type checking. In the `eq` case it's like this:

```
- + Main.hole [P]
 `--          a : Type
              m : Nat
            len : Nat
             eq : EqNat m len
          input : Vect m a
     --------------------------------
      Main.hole : Maybe (Vect len a)
```

And in the `(Same m)` case it's like this:

```
- + Main.hole_1 [P]
 `--            m : Nat
                a : Type
            input : Vect m a
     --------------------------------
      Main.hole_1 : Maybe (Vect m a)
```

So `eq` is something of a type `EqNat m len`, no one knows whether it's inhabitant or not, while `Same m` (or `Same len`) is definitely inhabitant which proves that m and len are equal.

Answer (score 1):

When you start with

```
exactLength : (len : Nat) -> (input : Vect m a) -> Maybe (Vect len a)
exactLength {m} len input  with (_)
  exactLength {m} len input  | with_pat = ?_rhs
```

and gradually extend the missing links until you reached

```
exactLength : (len : Nat) -> (input : Vect m a) -> Maybe (Vect len a)
exactLength {m} len input  with (checkEqNat m len)
  exactLength {m = m} len input  | Nothing = Nothing
  exactLength {m = len} len input  | (Just (Same len)) = Just input
```

you can see how idris can derive from the fact that `checkEqNat m len` returned a `Just (Same ...)` that it can then infer that `{m = len}`. AFAIK just writing `Just eq` is not a proof that `eq` is indeed inhabited.